# get android phone call in message

Tags: android, message, phone-call

Is there any idea that how can I get phone call as an MESSAGE from server. Like some buddy record voice and save as audio file, and I can get that file in my phone as an MP3 or something like that..
Thanks
-Akash

Comment: Well, something like that, but I want to integrate it in my application, like using my application I would be able to Record Voice & Send as well Receive from others.. 
Is it possible to integrate such kind of voice mail / voice message with our application..?

Answer (score 0):

Someone already [beat you to it, if you were thinking of using Google Voice unofficial api](http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/)

Though if you want to create your own VoiceMail-type service

- Buy a server.
- Write some web-service with api's that can upload and serve recorded content.
- Create an android application that can record voice data and upload it to the server.

IANAL so I don't know if this is legal in your country.